# The union of a countable set of countable sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

> Let $A$ be an countable set, and let $B_n$ be the set of all $n$-tuples $\left(a_1,\ldots,a_n\right)$
>
> $B_n$ is the union of a countable set of countable sets.

This question maybe about the English.

Is my rephrase right?

> $B_n$ is a countable set as the union of countable sets.

I think the quoted sentece has some problems in grammar or others?

Of course, that's only my judge, I'm not a native speaker and not so confident in the judge, so I asked this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the two sentences in question:

1. $B_n$ is the union of a countable set of countable sets.
2. $B_n$ is a countable set as the union of countable sets.

Sentence (1) is just fine, and sentence (2) is not a correct paraphrase of sentence (1).

- Sentence (2) says that $B_n$ is a countable set; sentence (1) does not say this.
- Sentence (1) says that $B_n$ is the union of **countably many** countable sets; sentence (2) merely says that $B_n$ is the union of some **arbitrary** family of countable sets, not necessarily a countable family.

Comment: aha, I misunderstood, thanks.

Comment: @HyperGroups: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase the question. Let $A$ be a countable set and let $B_n$ be the set of all $n$-tuples of elements of $A$.

For a fixed $n$ the set $B_n$ is countable by a diagonal argument.

I suspect the poser really wants to know about the set $B$ which is the union of all of the $B_n$. This set $B$ is also countable. To phrase this in terms of cardinal arithmetic,

$$
\begin{align}
& \operatorname{Card}(B_1) + \operatorname{Card}(B_2) + \operatorname{Card}(B_3) + \cdots \\[10pt]
& = \aleph_0 + \aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0 + \aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0 \cdot \aleph_0 + \cdots \\[10pt]
& = \aleph_0
\end{align}
$$